# How to put a template column in Vaadin-Grid?

Tags: html, user-interface, web, polymer, vaadin

I have the following table:

```
                <vaadin-grid id="temp" style=" height:70vh;">
                  <table>
                    <colgroup>
                      <col name="Column1"/> 
                      <col name="ColumnTime"/>                                
                    </colgroup> 
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th >Column1</th>
                        <th >ColumnTime</th>
                      </tr>
                   </thead>
                  </table>
                </vaadin-grid>
```

and my datasource:

```
{
    "Column1": "My Name",
    "ColumnTime": "<iron-icon icon='image:timelapse' style='cursor:pointer'></iron-icon>"

}
```

The problem is that the Vaadin-Grid does not deploy the Iron-Icon:

[image]

I have noticed that it is because it is within a SPAN element; Which is automatically added by Vaadin, any idea how to make the Iron-Icon deploy?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Data Renderers: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-grid/demo/formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try the HTML Renderer:

```
grid.getColumn("ColumnTime").setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer());
```

Comment: That API only applies to the Vaadin Java framework grid, not the web component, JavaScript grid.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the upcoming `v2.0.0` with actual template support.

https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/2.0.0-alpha1/demo/